# The nuance of using the word 'home' as an adverb/noun with or without prepositions

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

I was teaching my daughter the use of adverb *home*. I told her that we don't use any preposition before that word. That's how it is.

> I'm going home.

But then, when we talk about others home, we use preposition *(does it then become a noun? I'm not sure!)*

> I'm going ***to*** Henry's home.

I got confused when she asked that she has heard this in many Hollywood movies -

> Anybody home?

She asked further that if **her friend** asks on the phone, which question is correct -

> *"Rhyme, **are you home**?* **OR** 
>   *"Rhyme, **are you at your home?"***

She argued that if we are talking about **our home** we don't use preposition as I began my lesson with *(I merely did to make things simple!)* but then in the latest example, **her friend Sonia is asking** her about her (Rhyme's) home and certainly, Sonia is speaking from her home.

The case is quite similar to *I'm going **to** Henry's home.* Say, *Are you **at** Henry's home?* and so... *Are you **at** your home?*. If the second person is asking with preposition here, why don't they use preposition in ***Anybody home?*** After all, *anybody* is at least *someone*. We do say, *"I saw someone **at** his home while passing by."*

Furthermore, if **two sisters** are talking (they live in the same home), they don't need to use preposition in the same case of calling and asking on phone. One can simply ask another...

> *"Are you home?"*

The questions:

- If someone is asking about your home, do they have to use prepositions? (*Anybody home?* **over** *Are you at your home?*)
- If you are talking about your home, **in any case,** do you use a preposition?
- If two people (living under the same roof) are asking each other, do they use preposition? Because then it becomes your own home, again, rule no.1!

I already went through [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24635/when-should-i-use-to-before-home), [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27098/i-am-home-really), [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/why-is-to-not-used-before-home) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54336/playing-upstairs-vs-playing-home). But precisely, none of those questions answer my concern. Especially when someone asks you your location at your home.

Answer (score 3):

This hinges on parts of speech.

Remember that "home" can be used as a noun, an adjective, or an adverb.

In the uses of "home" which do not take an article (the, a) or a possessive (like my or our), home will be either an adjective or an [adverb](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/home#ld_entry_v2_jumplink_home_2). When describing a location, "I'm going home" is similar to "I'm going there"--the final word in both phrases is usually construed to be an [adverb of place](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/adverbs_types.php). Adverbs (of any kind) don't generally take articles.

However, "home" can also be a noun referring to a place of residence. That's the sense in which you would say "She is at her home" or "I am going to his home." This is basically a more intimate synonym for "house". (Realtors always use "home" when they mean to say "house" because "home" has much stronger emotional connotations.)

In the example:

> Rhyme, are you home? vs Rhyme, are you at home? vs Rhyme, are you at your home?

These are all grammatically correct. They may have slightly different nuances. I would use the first one if I expected Rhyme might not be home (like if we'd both gone somewhere together and then split up). Both the first and the second could be a general-purpose inquiry. The last version sounds like I'm making a distinction between whether she's at her home (vs. someone else's), or maybe like I'm specifically interested in the building somehow.

I could refer to my home with a preposition or article; examples include "I left it at home" or "The home I lived in at the time" or "My new home has a tile roof..." Preposition use isn't really dependent on whose home the speakers are discussing, or whether it's shared between them; it depends on whether they are using it as an adverb of place or a noun.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> If you are talking about your home, in any case, do you use a preposition?

Yes, quite often; here are a few samples:

- I'd prefer to watch the game at home.
- I can't believe she had the audacity to yell at me like that in my own home.
- In our home, we almost always say grace before dinner.