# Is this sentence correct? "We practice songs in here?"

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

Is the following sentence correct?

> We practice songs in here.

Some one told me that the preposition *'in'* shouldn't stand before the word *'here'*. I would like to know what you think.

Comment: To the folks looking in the review queue - I don't think this should be closed. It very specifically asks about using 'in' before 'here' and you can't research that very easily.

Comment: This other question might be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/103092

Comment: You could also find this helpful: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76626/usage-of-in-here-vs-just-here

Answer (score 2):

> We practice songs in here.
>
> We practice songs here.

Both the sentences answer the question **"Where do you practice songs?"** Both are correct!

**Here** is used when you wish to indicate a general location: it could be a city, a street, a neighborhood, and so on. 
**In here**, however, has a more specific reference: it is commonly
used when you enter a building, a room, an apartment, an inner place, and so on. In other words, it posits inside.